# How to get list of constraints of a table along with their respective column names in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to list all constraint names with their respective column name for a table. I am using the below mentioned code :

```
select * 
from sys.objects
where parent_object_id = object_id('qw') --this gives me the constraints lists but does not give me columns in which they are applied.

select * 
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('qw') -- this gives me the column list of the table.
```

My problem is that I am not able to join these two queries to get columns along with their constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174431(v=sql.105).aspx).